# How spring works for multiple @JmsListener on a single method

Tags: java, spring-jms

I want to make clear out that if I put multiple @jmsListener on a single method, then how it works?
If it will work parallel like multiple individual JMS listener?
Or it will work sequentially like just one JMS listener?

Like:

```
    @JmsListener(destination = "queue.name1", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
    @JmsListener(destination = "queue.name2", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
    @JmsListener(destination = "queue.name3", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
    @JmsListener(destination = "queue.name4", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
    public void receiveQueue(Message message, Session session) throws JMSException {
        //TODO for message queue consuming logic
    }
```

My question is will spring generate 4 individual JMS listener and work parallel or spring only generate 1 JMS listener and work sequentially for 4 different message queues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `JmsListener` annotation will build a JMS listener container, so there will be 4 JMS listeners working in parallel.  From the JavaDoc of the [JmsListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/annotation/JmsListener.html) annotation:

> Annotation that marks a method to be the target of a JMS message listener on the specified destination(). The containerFactory() identifies the JmsListenerContainerFactory to use to build the JMS listener container.